Loop Through HTML <li> in master page by Class Name using VB.Net
I have a master page with several menus that have submenus and finally menu items. What I would like to do is loop through each li (ideally by class="menu-item") on the server side to set their visibility to false and then show them one-by-one based on user permissions. The structure is generically this:


<ul id="Menu1">
  <li id="Menu1Opt1">
    <ul id="SubMenu1">
      <li id="SubMenu1Item1" class="menu-item" runat="server">
      <li id="SubMenu1Item2" class="menu-item" runat="server">
    </ul>
  </li>
 <li id="Menu1Opt2">
    <ul id="SubMenu2">
      <li id="SubMenu2Item1" class="menu-item" runat="server">
      <li id="SubMenu2Item2" class="menu-item" runat="server">
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>



I would like to be able to do something like this:

Private sub Boop()
For Each ele As HtmlElement In Master GetElementsByClassName("menu-item")
ele.visible = False
Next
End Sub


I'm not even sure if it needs to specify 'Master' because it's happening in the code-behind for the master page itself.
I can do:
SubMenu1Item1.visible = False
but there's a lot of them and I'd much rather loop them to make it easier to write and maintain.
What's the best way to accomplish this?  Thanks.
